# Export from Intellij/Illuminated Cloud all of the object's XML into one file

Tags: metadata, data, ide, xml, excel

My requirement is to get all Object's description. After some investigation we found that this isn't possible unless you get it from the XML. I created a new Intellij project of just the objects. I can individually open each object, copy the XML into a text editor, and push the data into an excel file. From here I can remove the columns I don't want. My issue is there are over 300 objects and I am looking for a less manual way of doing this.

Is there a way to export from Intellij all of the objects XML into one file?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried easy describe?

Comment: @JesseMilburn do you know if this app pulls the description field? We have tried another package that did something similar but did not actually pull the description.

Comment: It does not. You would need to write something with the metadata api. Or write something to churn through your xml object files since the metadata api has already retrieved what you need. Somebody else out there may have something written that does this for you. Sorry this doesn't help your immediate need.

Comment: Usually I use search by regular expression in sublime and copy lines that I need from search result (Which is a text file). It requires manual processing, but only a bit (write regexp, copy all lines that fall under it, remove garbage from copied lines, add extra tags (to make it valid XML) )

Comment: @Olivia, I sent you a direct email response, but I'll post the same answer here. Here's a way to create a simple CSV with object name in the first column and object description in the second:

`grep '    <description>' src/objects/*.object | sed -e 's/.*\/\([a-zA-Z0-9_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*\)\.object:.*<description>\(.*\)<\/description>/\1,\2/'`

You may or may not need something more complex than that, but it should give you a good starting point. Hope that helps!